# 2D Cellular Automaton: Initial conditions

Tags: cellular-automata

I'm trying to write in Mathematica for a 20x20 grid, with 100 colours, with 4 neighbours.
I want the initial conditions to be a 20x20 matrix consisting mainly of zeros.

```
CellularAutomaton[{100 (4 (100 - 1) + 1), {100, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
MatrixForm[Table[RandomInteger[], {20}, {20}]], 1]
```

Apparently init is not in the right form?

Comment: If you are looking for ways to visualize your cellular automaton there are several examples in the documentation.

Comment: Don't use `MatrixForm`; it is only intended for formatting output. `CellularAutomaton` wants a list for its 2nd argument (i.e., an expression with head `List`), not an expression with head `MatrixForm`, which is what you are giving it. `Table` returns a list  that can be used without further processing.

Answer (score 4):

Please read Documentation **[HERE](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellularAutomaton.html?q=CellularAutomaton)** - especially Details section and all the examples.

- Not enough specification: is it general, totalistic or outer totalistic rule CA?
- What is the rule?
- By 4 neighbors you mean [**Von Neumann neighborhood**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood)?
- 100 colors are too many - hard to find interesting rules. Perhaps you want [**continuos color CA**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0d6e8l44ia-mad)?

Well, assuming Von Neumann neighborhood, totalistic, 5 color CA you have (change 5 to 100 if you want but it will be boring):

Single non-zero cell initial condition:

```
dat = CellularAutomaton[
        {173452345235, {5, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}}, {1, 1}}, 
         SparseArray[{{11, 11} -> 3}, {20, 20}], 13];

Image3D[Rescale@dat, ColorFunction -> "RainbowOpacity"]
```

[image]

Random initial condition:

```
dat = CellularAutomaton[
       {14524645253, {5, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}}, {1, 1}}, 
        RandomInteger[4, {20, 20}], 20];

Image3D[Rescale@dat, ColorFunction -> "RainbowOpacity"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
MatrixPlot /@ CellularAutomaton[{100 (4 (100 - 1) + 1), {100, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
                                Table[RandomInteger[], {20}, {20}], 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]